# Conversion fails when casting varchar to int

Tags: sql-server

```
select '[' +e.empcode+'] ['+e.eId+']' as EmpName from employee e;
```

How can I cast e.eId which is varchar into int ?

**Error:**

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '] [' to data type int.

Comment: `e.eId` is the `int`, you are trying to concatenate `varchar` (`][`) and `int` (`e.eId`), so you need to convert `e.eId` to `varchar`

Comment: Do you want to cast a `VARCHAR` to `INT`, or do you want to construct a string containing the `eId`? Your question is somewhat nonsensical as written.

Comment: Thumb Rule is operands should be of same datatype on either sides of operator. If not SQL Server will try to convert implicitly according to the predefined rules. In your case SQL Server couldn't convert braces [] to INT and so the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `CAST` function:

```
select '[' + e.empcode + '] [' + CAST(e.eId AS VARCHAR) + ']' as EmpName from employee e;
```

Comment: I think you misread the question a bit. They ask how to go from `VARCHAR` to `INT`, not `INT` to `VARCHAR`. Technically, this wouldn't be a cast. It would be a parse.

Comment: @jpmc answer is correct as per the required result.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't think he wants to convert `e.eId` into `int`.  Rather, the RBDMS is giving the error because it is (mistakingly) trying to convert the things around it (e.g. `']['`) into an `int`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Hm. Well, the OP doesn't explicitly show what result they want, but looking at the code, that's probably what they want. Question is *very* poorly worded and asks for the wrong thing then.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, it is poorly worded, but deciphering such questions is part of the job.

Comment: I disagree. We should encourage users to clarify these things themselves. Then hopefully they'll think about them a little harder before they post next time.

Comment: His confusion partly stems from SQL Server, which is insinuating that he should be converting a `varchar` into an `int`, which I don't think he really wants.